# How to 'expect' something multiple times?

Tags: bash, expect

I am using the following script to handle multiple user inputs with `expect`:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

TEST1="Test text"
TEST2="Hello World"

expect -c '
    spawn /home/alexander/read.sh
    expect -re "Please enter some input:.*"
    send "'"$TEST1"'\r\n"
    expect -re "Please enter other input:.*"
    send "'"$TEST2"'\r\n"
    '
```

Here is a different version:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

TEST1="Test text"
TEST2="Hello World"

expect -c '
    spawn /home/alexander/tasks/update/test/Expect/read.sh
    expect {
       "Please enter some input:" { send "'"$TEST1"'\r"  }
       exp_continue
    }
    expect {
        "Please enter other input:" { send "'"$TEST2"'\r" }
    }
    '
```

The `read.sh` script looks like follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Please enter some input: " input_variable
echo "You entered: $input_variable"
read -p "Please enter other input: " other_variable
echo "You entered: $other_variable"
```

When I execute `read.sh` alone I am asked an input twice, which also is printed to stdout. The `expect` script, on the other hand, does not seem to handle the second input. The output I get is as follows:

```
spawn /home/alexander/read.sh
Please enter some input: Test text

You entered: Test text
Please enter other input:
```

What am I doing wrong, how to fix this?

Remarks:

- The script needs to be a bash script with the bash-shebang.
- Adding `exp_continue` in the first script results in an `command returned bad code: -101` error.

Comment: Remove '\n' from send command in expect?

Comment: With `exp_continue` give an error `command returned bad code: -101` and removing the `\n` does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
#!/bin/bash

TEST1="Test text"
TEST2="Hello World"

expect -c '
    spawn /tmp/read.sh
    expect {
       "Please enter some input:" { send "'"$TEST1"'\r"
                                   exp_continue
                                  }
        "Please enter other input:" { send "'"$TEST2"'\r"
                                      exp_continue
                                    }
    }'
```

Comment: Probably all you missed was `interact`

Comment: What does `interact` do?

Comment: Do I really need `interact`? I have seen other expect examples which did not use `interact`. According to the man pages I do not need it in the context of the given question.

Comment: You need to use `exp_continue` or `interact`. Else, `expect` would terminate after sending `$TEST2`... Thus, the spawned process would lose its `stdout` & there will be no `expect` running, which would dump spawned process's `stdout` to terminal.

Comment: Actually, the third pattern to match there is `eof`: `expect {"please 1" {send ""; exp_continue} "please 2" {send ""; exp_continue} eof}`

Comment: I'm curious (& probably a very stupid question...), what would happen if spawned process does an `exec 1>/dev/null`. Does it trigger `eof`?